# Linq-to-sql Delete a record with FK constraints

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to SubmitChanges and ignore deletes that cause Foreign Key constraint errors?

Say I have object A and B. B's Primary Key is a Foreign Key in A. Now I change a record A in which I replace B for another B and delete the original B. An error will occur when the deleted B is referenced in another record A (or other tables containing B as Foreign Key). Is it possible to ignore the error and let the changes be made in the database, without deleting the old B?

```
A rec_a = (from a in db.As where a.id == some_id).First();
B rec_b_old = rec_a.B;
rec_a.B = null;
db.Bs.DeleteOnSubmit(rec_b_old);
rec_a.B = some_other_b;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: You might want to look into Cascading Deletes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994587/sql-server-2005-cascading-delete

Comment: if the old B is still being referenced by either records in A or some other table, isn't deleting that row of B the wrong thing to do?  Why would you want to delete a row that's still being referenced?  If you need to allow that, remove the FK constraint, since the FK is there to intentionally prevent what you want to do.

Comment: BTW, if the intent is "point the A record at the new B, and then delete the old B if it's not being referenced anymore", then I would do the rec_a.B change and submit that and then either do the delete of B as a best-effort change on its own (which you would have to back out on failure) or just look at its navigation properties to try and figure out if it's still used.  It might help to explain a little bit as to why the 'B' record is being deleted here, though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make two calls to `SubmitChanges()`:

```
A rec_a = (from a in db.As where a.id == some_id).First();
B rec_b_old = rec_a.B;
rec_a.B = null;
rec_a.B = some_other_b;
db.SubmitChanges();
db.Bs.DeleteOnSubmit(rec_b_old);
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(SqlException) { } // Ignore failed delete.
```

The second one might fail and in that case just ignore it. It is possible to try to submit everything, dig out the failing update/delete, remove it from the pending list and retry. However it requires far more code so I don't think it's worth to do it here.

Another solution is to put a trigger on the A table that deletes the B record if it is orphaned.

Comment: This is exactly how I solved. A fellow developer pointed me in this direction. Thx anyways!

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL does not support cascading delete operations.  You will need to either tell the database itself to do that or delete the child rows yourself first.

See [Insert, Update, and Delete Operations (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx) for a detailed explanation.